# First jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-plugins

Im trying to make my first jquery plugin.. but actually i dont know what im doing wrong here.

```
$(document.ready(function()
{
    var plugin = (function()
        {
            //this function is not accessible from the outside
            function privateFunction()
            {

            }

            //these functions are
            return
            {
                alert1: function()
                {
                    alert('Hallo');
                },

                alert2: function()
                {
                    alert("hi");
                }

            }

        })()

        //but it is not working :/
        plugin.alert1();
});
```

it is not executing one of the alerts. Am i putting some semicolons wrong?
i checked if all were closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript's automatic semicolon insertion will add a semicolon after `return` and `undefined` is returned.

Your code will look like

```
return;
{...
```

Replace

```
return
        {
```

Should be

```
return {
```

You're also missing the `)` after `document` in the first line of code.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var plugin = (function() {
    //this function is not accessible from the outside
    function privateFunction() {
      // Code Here
    }

    //these functions are
    return {
      alert1: function() {
        alert('Hallo');
      },

      alert2: function() {
        alert("hi");
      }
    };
  }());

  //but it is not working :/
  plugin.alert1();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: oh wow.. well i didnt think about that.. probably because of my standard structure :P

Thanks!

Comment: yea sure but i had to wait some minutes because it was too early